# QGIS Raster Visualization Problems from a self-produced .asc file

Tags: qgis, raster, ascii

I have been creating .asc raster files by saving a numpy array with numpy.savetxt and the following header:
header = "ncols        %s\n" % ncols
header += "nrows        %s\n" % nrows
header += "xllcorner    %s\n" % xll
header += "yllcorner    %s\n" % yll
header += "cellsize     %s\n" % cellsize
header += "NODATA_value  -99999"

After producing the .asc files I load them into QGIS and they are by default given a style with min: nan, and max: nan. If I go into the Style dialog, set to Stretch to min/max, and change the min and max to match the appropriate range for the source file (eg 0 to 40), the preview thumbnail shows a pixelated mess and the raster shows as completely black.

Sometimes the raster shows up fine if I just hit apply, but then reverts to all black once I hit OK. If I am zoomed very far in (well within the limits of the raster), then sometimes the raster shows up fine and sometimes it doesn't.

Source and generated .asc files here:
https://github.com/mrlmautner/PrecipRasters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GeneratedRaster.asc header, you specify:

```
ncols        98
nrows        70
```

But there are are only 69 rows.  Change to:

```
ncols        98
nrows        69
```

And gdal can read the raster correctly, so I presume QGIS will be able to as well.

Comment: Thanks! You were correct, I found a resampling definition error in my Python code.